# Hide Application when outside the desktop application is clicked

Tags: c++, flutter, system-tray

I made an utility/tray application using flutter and i want it to hide when i click outside the application. How can we do this? I researched quite some time but i could not get the answer to this.

I looked out for window_manager, bitsdojo, googling, youtube and documentation. But could not get the answers.

Comment: Do you mean to hide your app when it goes out of focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window_manager, which helps to find the focus.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WindowListener {
  @override
  void initState() {
    windowManager.addListener(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    windowManager.removeListener(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }

 
  @override
  void onWindowFocus() {
    // do something when app gets into focus state
  }

  @override
  void onWindowBlur() {
    // do something when app gets into inactive/blur state
  }
}
```